# What is an appropriate translation for "Gentlemen Weavers"?

Tags: traduction, noms

I've come up with: Messieurs Tisseurs or Messieurs Tisserand. Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Howdy. But do you mean like you're addressing those weavers, or are you rather talking about weavers who are not professionals here? You may [update](http://french.stackexchange.com/posts/22011/edit) your question accordingly with some more context. Thank you!

Comment: Without the answers to the question asked, I'd still say the answer is 'messieurs les tisserands'.  Tisseur is not a profession.  And you can't messieurs a group without an article..